# 'async' modifier cannot be used here in typescript react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am getting an error in `aync`, that the `async` modifier cannot be used here:

```
private async getValue= (acc: Access): void => {   
          await this.service.getForm('');
        }
```

Seems like I am doing something wrong in the method declaration.

```
private async getValue= (acc: Access): void => {
```

Comment: SO requires that the *exact* error message be embedded as text in your question. Please `edit` to include the error message you received. These message are helpful to experienced devs who will often immediately know your issue/solution based on the message. Also, it helps future visitors who receive the same message to find your post (read possible upvotes). Finally, copy-passing the error message into search engines can help devs find your answer for you. As is, it's *possible* that the SO platform could delete your post as not compliant. Read topics at  StackOverflow.com/help for more info.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use the `async` keyword in an arrow function before the declaration - you will end up with a syntax error. Consider moving it before the parenthesis.

```
private getValue = async (acc: Access) => {   
   await this.service.getForm('');
}
```

Comment: The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type,

Comment: I believe we need to use Promise<void>

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html#asyncawait-support-in-es6-targets-node-v4  you can remove `: void` here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `void` also. This way you can use `this` in the method:

```
private getValue = async (acc: Access) => {   
   await this.service.getForm('');
}
```